# C# Generic API Caller With Different Request and Response

Tags: c#

I have a front end MVC application that uses a generic web caller to access a back end API. Currently it always uses the same request and response object types.

```
public static async Task<T> CallPostWebApi<T>(T t, string serviceUrl)
```

which converts t into json and passes to the API

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
var formData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, formData);
```

and returns the same object type as the response:

```
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
```

so I can call this like:

```
return await ApiCaller.CallPostWebApi(inputModel, _url);
```

but what need to be able to do now is send a different request object to the response object. So I want to be able to call

```
return await ApiCaller.CallPostWebAPI(inputModel, outputModel, _url);
```

I have tried implementing the static method in the ApiCaller using different generic combinations but none seems to work.

Comment: You may want to rename this, it's technically incorrect and misleading: `var formData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`. `formData` should be `jsonContent` or only `content` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fairly trivial to do if you use 2 generic parameters:

```
public static async Task<TResponse> CallPostWebApi<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, string serviceUrl)
{
    ...
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(data);
}
```

Notice, however, that you'll have to specify both parameters when calling the method:

```
var response = await CallPostWebApi<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>(request, "url");
```

Comment: that's great, thanks. The call looks like: var response = await CallPostWebApi(request, response, url)